# How to tag more than 20 people in Facebook 1

Tags: facebook

Nowadays I'm able to tag only 19 members . I want to increase my tagging list up to 50 members in single post . And I've promoted as page admin for one page, in that I'm unable to tag even single person. kindly try to help me and solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't tag more than 20 people on Facebook. This is something that you'd have to consult Facebooks customer service about if you wish to bring it up for discussion.

***TL;DR You can't.***